# Where to find free jquery newsticker plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, news-ticker

I need something like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Horizontal-Text-Scrolling-Simple-Marquee/, but with prev and next controls (and free, I've seen some on CodeCanyon). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery News Ticker is an open source library that scrolls, has forward and backward controls, as well as advanced features like pausing. Hope this helps..

http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/

The website explain in detail, but here are all of the granular options for you:

```
$(function () {
    $('#js-news').ticker(
        speed: 0.10,           // The speed of the reveal
        ajaxFeed: false,       // Populate jQuery News Ticker via a feed
        feedUrl: false,        // The URL of the feed
                           // MUST BE ON THE SAME DOMAIN AS THE TICKER
        feedType: 'xml',       // Currently only XML
        htmlFeed: true,        // Populate jQuery News Ticker via HTML
        debugMode: true,       // Show some helpful errors in the console or as alerts
                           // SHOULD BE SET TO FALSE FOR PRODUCTION SITES!
        controls: true,        // Whether or not to show the jQuery News Ticker controls
        titleText: 'Latest',   // To remove the title set this to an empty String
        displayType: 'reveal', // Animation type - current options are 'reveal' or 'fade'
        direction: 'ltr'       // Ticker direction - current options are 'ltr' or 'rtl'
        pauseOnItems: 2000,    // The pause on a news item before being replaced
        fadeInSpeed: 600,      // Speed of fade in animation
        fadeOutSpeed: 300      // Speed of fade out animation
    );
});
```

Comment: This is really great, but I need something that will display more than one information and have them kind of pass by on their own, like the one in the demo I linked in the question.